# Rewrite condition rule to see if there are variables after the slash

Tags: .htaccess

Here's what I'm looking to do:

if http://acme.com/ has nothing after the slash rewrite to http://www.acme.com/

if http://www.acme.com/ has nothing after the slash do not rewrite

if http://acme.com/ has stuff after the slash (http://acme.com/abc/def) then rewrite to http://www.foobar.com/abc/def

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5684940/problem-detecting-empty-request-uri-with-apache-mod-rewrite) on stackoverflow.com. I think it explains everything you need.